# Что не так с react-scripts?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webstorm

Всем доброго времени суток. После переустановки системы (Linux Mint 18) и WebStorm перестал запускаться проект (раньше всё было без проблем). Порядок действий таков: 
1) Клонирую из gutHub
2) `npm init`, затем, раньше, среда предлагала автоматически установить всё, что нужно, сейчас делаю `npm install` (правильно ведь?)
3) npm start, после чего запускается `react-scripts start`, терминал возвращает:

```
> /home/goosenjuice/WebstormProjects/ResumeBank/Front/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:
> const {
>       ^
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
>     at startup (node.js:136:18)
>     at node.js:966:3
```

и ещё вот что

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-53-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! resume_bank@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the resume_bank@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the resume_bank package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs resume_bank
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls resume_bank
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/goosenjuice/WebstormProjects/ResumeBank/Front/npm-debug.log
goosenjuice@goosenjuice-Lenovo-B570e ~/WebstormProjects/Resum
```

Есть идеи, что можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идеи есть:) Просто обновите node.js. `react-scripts` не будут работать с **node v4.2.6** из-за того, что последний не поддерживает ES2015 синтаксис. См. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app:

```
You’ll need to have Node >= 6 on your local development machine
```

см. также https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2826

Comment: Дай Б-г тебе здоровья, мил человек))) Установил себе последнюю версию через nvm и всё запустилось. А изначально скачивал node.js, разархивировал и указал в настройках webStorm, где папка из архива лежит, думал, всё ровно. После Вашего поста, забил `node -v`, оказалось, что всё равно используется старая версия!